Solved Installing GitLab runner repo on rhel 9 (oracle linux 9) failing
I have a problem installing the repository for gitlab runner.
Running as Root:
curl -L "https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/runner/gitlab-runner/script.rpm.sh" | sudo bash 
is failing with
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0 curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection reset by peer, errno 104
I tried to add -k but same error. I can not find the problem or any solution.
Thanks for help in advance
[Solution / Problem]
Firewall

May be firewall
